# Add program to applications list in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

I have installed Xmind on Linux Mint. It does not come in a DEB, and I had to unzip a bunch of files to my home directory. Now I want xmind to show up in my start menu applications. Is there a way I can do this?

I want to be able to open the start menu and just start typing "xmind" and have the application show up.

Comment: Yes, but the DEsktop can play a part. It's different for KDE, Mate, Cinnamon ....   On my current (Ubuntu) DEsktop I right click the menu, select 'Applications Menu' then 'Edit Menu', navigate to where I want then hit "+new item"....   If I were using Linux Mint with the same DEsktop I'd expect it to be the same...    If you want it to perfectly match your DEsktop, you'll have to tell us which Mint (and DEsktop) you are running.

Comment: Right click on start menu icon -> Configure -> Menu Tab -> Open Menu Editor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to create a `xmind.desktop` file. Look for a sample in `/usr/share/applications` and copy one to `~/.local/share/applications/xmind.desktop`, and change the appropriate lines. The most important lines will be:

```
Name=
Exec=
GenericName=
Categories=
Icon=
Comment=
Terminal=false
```

The `categories` should be a semi-colon delimited list of the menu categories in which you want the program to appear. The `exec` should point the complete pathname of the executable. The `genericname` will be the name that actually appears in the menu. The `comment` is what appears when you hover the mouse over the menu entry. The `icon` can be an icon name if the icon is in a standard icon directory or a path.